Añadir lenguaje de programación al selector de modo de lenguaje en VS Code
Estoy trabajando, con VS Code, en un cuaderno Jupyter (.ipynb) con celdas que contienen código escrito en diferentes lenguajes de programación. Tengo instaladas las extensiones Jupyter, Python, R, SQL, así como Polyglot Notebooks. El kernel que he asociado a este cuaderno es Python 3.12.6.
En las celdas de código, aparece un botón que permite seleccionar el modo de lenguaje de celda. Al clicar en este botón, aparece un dropdown con muchos lenguajes (python, sql, html, perl...) pero no aparece R. Si selecciono cualquiera de los lenguajes que aparecen, esta selección se guarda para la siguiente vez que trabajo sobre el cuaderno.
El problema está en las celdas que contienen código R, que, aunque este lenguaje no aparece en el dropdown, sí lo reconoce en la detección automática. Sin embargo, esta selección automática de lenguaje R no se guarda y la siguiente vez que quiero trabajar con el cuaderno ha asignado el lenguaje python a todas las celdas identificadas con R.
Lo que pretendo (porque es lo que supongo que debe funcionar) es que R aparezca como uno de los lenguajes a seleccionar en el dropdown. He modificado el settings.json con
"polyglot-notebook.kernelEnvironmentVariables": {
    "PATH": "/usr/local/bin:$PATH",
    "R_HOME": "/usr/lib/R",
    "JUPYTER_PATH": "~/.local/share/jupyter"}

pero no funciona. ¿Cómo puedo conseguirlo?
